# Why does Function.bind("foo").call("bar") always refer this to "foo"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I just experienced a behavior in JS which I couldn't understand: I wanted to create a method which calls String.prototype.replace with some args given, therefore I came up with that:

```
String.prototype.replace.bind("foo", /bar/g, function(){}).call
```

I guessed that I would get a function where I would just have to throw a string into to get my replace. Instead, I always get the initial `this`-value (in this case `foo`) returned.

Now my questions are:

- Why is JS behaving like that? What does bind really return and how can I get the `this`-parameter of `.call()`?
- Is there another way of doing what I want to do without creating a wrapper function?

Comment: So you want to bind the arguments, but not the `this`?

Comment: Yes, or let's say: I want to replace the this later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why it's happening

You pass some `this` value from `call` to the function returned by `bind`. `bind`, however, ignores that value and calls the original function with the bound `this` (e.g. `foo`). In fact, `bind` is *meant* to bind the `this` value. The `arguments` you can bind is rather something additional.

### Solving it

Without a wrapper function I don't think you can do what you want. However, with a wrapper function you could do what you're after:

```
Function.prototype.bindArgs = function() {
    var args = arguments,
        func = this;

    return function(context) {
        return func.apply(context, args);
    }
};
```

E.g.

```
var func = function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(this, a, b, c);
};

var bound = func.bindArgs(1, 2, 3);
bound([1]); // [1] 1 2 3
bound({a: 1}); // {a: 1} 1 2 3
```

Comment: Well, the first part is pretty much it. The second part is senseless for me, it would just add unnecessary overhead to my code.

Answer (score 2):

Function.bind returns a new function that, when called, will always call the original function with the bound context.

One could implement Function.bind like this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
    var origFunction = this;
    return function() {
        return origFunction.apply(context, arguments);
    };
};
```

You can try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/HeRU6/

So when you do `somefunction.bind("foo")`, it returns a new function. Calling this new function will always call `somefunction` with `"foo"` as context.

You can write a function that would bind only the arguments, and not the context:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var origFunction = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        console.log(args, arguments);
        return origFunction.apply(this, Array.prototype.concat.apply(args, arguments));
    };
};

a = function() { console.log(this, arguments); };

b = a.curry(1, 2);
b(); // Window [1, 2]
b(3); // Window [1, 2, 3]
b.call("foo", 4); // "foo" [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: To pass `arguments`, you'd rather have to use `.apply`.

Comment: What you wrote would support what I wanted to do: You set the this inside of the wrapper function, therefore I may replace it later on.

Comment: oops, it was `origFunction.apply(context, arguments);` :)

Comment: Also perhaps `return` the new function's return value, now you can't use `origFunction`s return value.

Comment: I would write it like that: `Function.prototype.bind = function(){ var args = arguments, that = this; return function(){ that.apply(args[0], Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1) } }`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is JS behaving like that?

Because that's the way it's defined in the [standard](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.4.5).

> What does bind really return and how can I get the this-parameter of .call()?

`g = f.bind(foo, bar, ...)` is exactly the same as `function g() { return f.call(foo, bar, ...); }`
Since there is no `this` in `g`, you cannot get it back from the call.

> Is there another way of doing what I want to do without creating a wrapper function?

Probably not.